# Ending a video segment on a non-key frame while preserving codec

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec

I want to extract a segment from the middle of a video while keeping the original encoding. I understand that I need to start that segment on a keyframe. However, I would think that it should in principle be possible to end the segment on an arbitrary frame. Can anyone confirm that and provide an example for how to achieve this using ffmpeg? It seems that `-c:v copy` enforces key frames at both ends and the same is true when using the `-segment` option.

My current commands have the form (times and frames are examples and do not match)

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i test.mp4 -to 00:00:10 -c:v copy test_cut.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_frames 80,140 test_%03d.mp4
```

Comment: The lat frame of an extracted file need not be a KF. Why do you think it is?

Comment: For example: if test.mp4 has key frames 80 and 250, the option segment cuts on 80 and 250 even if I specify 80, 140 or 80, 81.

Comment: It seems that the first command (based on times rather than frame indices) does allow to specify arbitrary end times, as can be checked by counting the number of frames in the cut video.

Comment: The segment muxer, in default mode, cuts only on KF so a  non-KF segment_frame entry won't be honoured precisely but this relates to the start of each segment, not the end.